# Prevent Params to display in browser via jquery ajax call.

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I just want to prevent my parameter is being display in my browser using firebug/debug tool.

i.e.

[image]

is there any way to hide these details so registration can be done via ajax.

I am using following code in my javascript:

```
$( "#myform" ).submit(function( event ) {
            event.preventDefault();
            var email = $('#email').val();
            var password = $('#password').val();
            var mobile = $('#mobile').val();
            $(".blog-header").mask("Waiting...");
            var request = $.ajax({
                                url: "registrarscript.php",
                                type: "get",
                                data: "box="+jQuery("#myform").serialize(),
                                cache: false,
                                dataType: "html"
                            });
                            request.done(function( msg ) {
                                $('.blog-header').html(msg);
                                $(".blog-header").unmask();
                            });
                            request.fail(function( jqXHR, textStatus ) {
                                alert( "Request failed: " + textStatus );
                            });
    });
```

Thanks

Comment: That is Impossible! And you should not be using a GET

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not really. Doing so would also not provide any real security benefit. The client already has access to the JS and they know their password an email so you've got nothing to gain by hiding those details from them (even if it was possible).

I would suggest updating your registration page to be a `POST` rather than `GET` request so that the password isn't exposed in the query string. (You don't want that info getting logged server side or in the browsers history)

It is safe to have your registration page be **AJAX**. As long as you're hosting over **HTTPS**, the user's credentials won't be sniffed in transit and you aren't really losing anything security-wise.

Short answer is no. You can certainly obfuscate the data before sending it but if your concern is for security, then this won't be any help.